# Программно установить системный будильник

Tags: java, android

Такая задача. Мне нужно из моего приложения программно установить будильник (родной будильник андроида). Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: есть sleep time приложение посмотри в нем, возможно то что нужно.

Comment: Не могу сказать что у андроида есть вменяемый нормальный родной будильник. Будильник старенькой нокии - который поднимает трубу с выключегого состояния - да. А у андроида это программа, которая интегрируется в среду не хуже чем там плеер или блокнот. Т.е. будильник выглядит как полноценный будильник, но по сути не является системным - является он обычной софтиной, у которой иконку выставили "вперёд".

Comment: У андроида нет "родного" будильника. Это самое обычное приложение, причем обычно оно называется "Clock", включает в себя еще часы, секундомер и таймер, но при этом частенько у каждого производителя свое собственное.